# Built-in operator candidates

Tags: c++, built-in, overload-resolution, candidate

> C++03 $13.6/1- "[...]If there is a
>   user-written candidate with the same
>   name and parameter types as a built-in
>   candidate operator function, the
>   built-in operator function is hidden
>   and is not included in the set of
>   candidate functions."

I am not sure about the intent of this quote from the Standard. Is it possible to define a user defined candidate function that has the same name and type as a built-in operator?

e.g. the below which is clearly wrong.

```
int operator+(int)
```

So what does this quote mean?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but related: ["Can I define an operator overload that works with built-in / intrinsic / primitive types?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.10)

Comment: I think a better example might be "int operator+(int,int);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick one of those in 13.6. Like

> For every pointer or enumeration type T, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> bool operator<(T, T);
> bool operator>(T, T);
> bool operator<=(T, T);
> bool operator>=(T, T);
> bool operator==(T, T);
> bool operator!=(T, T);
> ```

So

```
enum Kind { Evil, Good };
bool operator<(Kind a, Kind b) { ... }
```